# Witir browser.link(id: 'identifier').wait_until_present 6.17.0 Usage Issue

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir, deprecation-warning

The `Watir` `gem` has updated one of their browser methods, `wait_until_present` and it's confusing me.

https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/watir/Watir/Waitable#wait_until_present-instance_method

...says that I should use it like this:

```
browser.link(id: 'identifier').wait_until_present
```

However I'm getting this error instead:

```
WARN Watir [DEPRECATION] ["wait_until_present"] Watir::Anchor#wait_until_present is deprecated. Use Watir::Anchor#wait_until(&:present?) instead.
```

It's also reported at the bottom [here](http://watir.com/guides/waiting/) however that English is unclear, as is the solution above.

The reported `gem` similar `methods` are as follows:

```
wait_for_enabled
wait_for_exists
wait_for_present
wait_for_writable
wait_until
wait_until_present
wait_while
wait_while_present
```

So I don't know which one to use, before the fact I can't get it to work.

Questions:

- Which one should I use?
- How is it properly used?  There's a link on a form that I need to click before a field is viewable.
- What does this mean: `Use Watir::Anchor#wait_until(&:present?)`

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Found it in other documentation:

```
browser.text_field(name: "new_user_first_name").wait_until(&:present?).click
```

Comment: You don't have call wait_until. WATIR automatically waits for the link to be present when it calls the click method.

Comment: OK then.  But the question was about the syntax of this, even if for the wrong element.  I found the syntax.  I am using `wait_until(&:present?)` in other instances.